# Utilizando Enum no Java

Tags: java, enums

Olá, pessoal.
O programa deve gerar aleatoriamente um valor "Cara" ou "Coroa", porém utilizando Enum.
Não está claro pra mim como implementar o enunciado abaixo utlizando Enum. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?
Para gerar aleatoriamente as opções cara e coroa, crie um ENUM que contenha os dois valores e um método que faça uso da classe java.util.Random para selecionar um dos valores do um dos valores do ENUM.

Eu já fiz isso aqui: (Não sei se é isso)

```
    public enum Jogo {
     CARA(0), COROA(1);
    private int indice;

     Jogo(int i) {
         this.indice = i;
     }

    public int getIndice() {
         return this.indice;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Jogar cara ou coroa pressupõe aleatoriedade, então seu programa precisa ter um método que consiga escolher de forma randômica um dos valores do enum que você criou. Java tem uma classe chamada [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), que se preocupa em gerar valores aleatórios para você. Mais especificamente, tem [este](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) método aqui:

```
public int nextInt(int bound)
```

Ele vai gerar um inteiro aleatório entre 0 e o limite que você especificar no parâmetro de forma exclusiva, ou seja, para gerar um número aleatório entre 0 e 10, você deve informar 11 no parâmetro.

Outra coisa que você precisa é de um método que o compilador cria pra você toda vez que você usa um Enum: `values()`. Esse método retorna um array com todos os valores do Enum na ordem em que você os declarou lá dentro dele:

```
Moeda.values()[0]; // vai retornar Moeda.CARA
Moeda.values()[1]; // vai retornar Moeda.COROA
```

Atenção: isso não tem relação com essa variável `indice` que você criou. Aqui você está acessando a posição 0 e a posição 1 do array. Como você declarou CARA e depois COROA, o `values` cria o array com CARA na primeira posição do array (0) e COROA na segunda posição (1). Na verdade, essa variável `indice` é desnecessária.

Agora ficou fácil: você vai gerar um número aleatório entre 0 e 1, vai no array de valores, recupera o valor do enum armazenado naquela posição e pronto.

Essa luz é suficiente para você fazer seu exercício. Quebre um pouco a cabeça e, caso evolua, edite o código na sua pergunta, atualizando com o que você conseguiu e, em caso de dúvidas, comente nesta resposta aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Basta gerar um número aleatório entre 0 e 1. Use esse valor como índice da enumeração usando o método **values()**.

```
package moeda;

import java.util.Random;

public class CaraCoroa {

    public enum Moeda {
        CARA, COROA;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("sortear() = " + sortear());
        System.out.println("sortear() = " + sortear());
        System.out.println("sortear() = " + sortear());
        System.out.println("sortear() = " + sortear());
        System.out.println("sortear() = " + sortear());
    }

    private static Moeda sortear(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int indice = random.nextInt(2);
        
        Moeda moeda = Moeda.values()[indice];
        return moeda;
    }
}
```